# ngClass doesn't work with custom selector and extended component

Tags: angular

I have several slideUp/Down blocks on my page. It means when user clicks on the title of block its content appears and disappears. But content is different on each block. To not duplicate code I have created basic aside component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({})
export class AsideComponent implements OnInit {

    class = 'open';
    contentVisible = true;

    scrHeight:any;
    scrWidth:any;

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    getScreenSize(event?) {
        this.scrHeight = window.innerHeight;
        this.scrWidth = window.innerWidth;
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    constructor() {
        this.getScreenSize();
        if(this.scrWidth < 576) {
            this.hideContent()
        }
    }

    showContent() {
        this.contentVisible = true;
        this.class = 'open';
    }

    hideContent() {
        this.contentVisible = false;
        this.class = '';
    }

    toggleVisible() {
        if (this.contentVisible) {
            this.hideContent()
        } else {
            this.showContent()
        }
    }
}
```

And real blocks extend it like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AsideComponent} from "../aside/aside.component";

@Component({
    selector: '[appAsideTools]',
    templateUrl: './aside-tools.component.html',
})
export class AsideToolsComponent extends AsideComponent {}
```

And I include asideTool like this:

```
<div class="aside-itm" [ngClass]="class" appAsideTools></div>
```

Of course there is also html inside exactly appAsideTools component:

```
<div class="aside-title" (click)="toggleVisible()">
    <span>title</span>
    <i class="arr-dn-ic"></i>
</div>

<div class="aside-toggle-box" [slide-down]="contentVisible">
    <nav class="aside-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="arr-r">></i> 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="arr-r">></i> 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="arr-r">></i> 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Everything works. Content appears and disappears. But `ngClass` doesn't work here:

```
<div class="aside-itm" [ngClass]="class" appAsideTools></div>
```

Before I used typically:

```
<app-aside-tools class="aside-itm" [ngClass]="class"></app-aside-tools>
```

And it worked...

Angular version is 8.3.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({})
export class AsideComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class.open')
  get isOpen {
    return this.open;
  }
}
```

And remove `[ngClass]` also

Comment: Thank you! All styles included with single file in app.component.html, where should I use your code ? Here @Component({}) ?

Comment: At first you can try to move 'open' into `styles.scss`, which placed in the root folder to verify that error happens due to ViewEncapsulation.

Comment: Yes, you can try here: 
`@Component({
  styles: ':host(.open) { }'
})`

Comment: But the problem is not in styles. Problem that class doesn't appear. If I change class manually styles work

Comment: So I meant that open class is not attached to element

Comment: Also you can try it:
@HostBinding('class.open') isOpen() {
  return this.class; // would be better if it'll be just boolean variable
};

Comment: The problem, that I can't see where you use your 'class' variable in AsideToolsComponent.

Comment: you can see it in my post. It is in showContent() method.

Comment: But where you bind this property to the dom element? :)

Comment: `<div class="aside-itm" [ngClass]="class" appAsideTools></div>` - in my post ) and i worked when I used typical selectors..

Comment: @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen() { return this.class; } and remove ngClass

Comment: I have done as you say.. And first time class gets 'open'. I have done it with return this.contentVisible; so it returns bool. But when I click on title and `contentVisible` gets fals - class 'open' is not removed .. (

Comment: `@HostBinding('class.open') contentVisible;` this is the solution

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that you will get rid of the close param)
With close param it should also work because these variables toggle in one place)
Hope it helps.